# What is the calling function in R?

Tags: r, environment

> One of the most important things to know about the evaluation of arguments to a function is that supplied arguments and default arguments are treated differently. The supplied arguments to a function are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the calling function. The default arguments to a function are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the function.

I don't quite understand what it is meant by calling function. Is it the function that is invoked (like in interactive sesion with function that has named assigned you type name and hit enter). If yes how evaluation frame of the callinig function differs from evaluation frame of the function?

Comment: This is saying that when you call `seq(from = 0, to = 3 + 2)`, the `3 + 2` is evaluated in the environment in which `seq` is called (the global environment here), but since the call doesn't specify `by`, its default `((to - from)/(length.out - 1))` is evaluated within the environment created by the function (by which point `to` has already been evaluated and stored for use). This is why a call like `to <- 3; seq(from = 0, to = to + 2)` can be evaluated sensibly.

Comment: I caught myself in an idea that I don't fully understand the supplied arguments too. Are they the same as local?

Comment: "Supplied" just means parameters specified in the call, so `from` and `to` above. "Default" parameters are those that are set in the function definition, e.g. `by` above. If no value is supplied for that parameter, the default from the definition is used. Local variables are a different way of categorizing; it just refers to any variable in the current environment (as opposed to ones in a parent environment, which are treated similarly to default parameters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First change to standard terms.  The arguments that are used in the function definition are the *formal arguments* and the arguments that are passed to the function when calling it are the *actual arguments*.  (The [quoted passage](http://colinfay.me/r-language-definition/functions.html) in the question is referring to the actual arguments when it uses the nonstandard term, supplied arguments.)

Consider two cases via example.

### Case 1

Below `f` has the formal argument `x` and when `f` is called in the last line of code there are no actual arguments.

Now when `f` is called in the last line of code `x` gets the value 2 because `x` is not set until it is used and when it is used `a` is looked up within the function where it has the value 2, *not* in the caller where it has the value 1.

```
a <- 1
f <- function(x = a) {
   a <- 2
   x
}
f()
## [1] 2
```

### Case 2

On the other hand the actual arguments are evaluated in the caller.  In the last line of code below `x` is set to 1 because that is the value of `b` in the caller.  Again, `x` is not evaluated until it is used but now even though `b` has been set to 2 in the function itself this has no effect on `x`.  `x` is set to 1, not 2.

```
b <- 1
g <- function(x) { b <- 2; x + b }
g(b)
## [1] 3
```

### Other

Although this covers the two cases in the quote note that there exists another case which is the situation that occurs when `x` is referred to in a function but is not defined in the function.  In the code below `a` is a free variable in `g` since `a` is not an argument or otherwise defined in `g`.  In this case when `gg` (which equals `g`) is called R attempts to look up `a` in the function `g` and fails but the next place it looks is *not* the caller (where `a` is 1) but the environment in which the function was *defined*, i.e. the environment where the word `function` appears and `a` is 2 in that environment.

```
 a <- 1
 f <- function() {
        a <- 2
        g <- function() a
 }
 gg <- f()
 gg()
 ## [1] 2
```

This is referred to as lexical scoping since one can tell where the free variables are looked up by simply looking at the function definitions.